# initializing UI with SQL values

Tags: android, sqlite, user-interface

Here is my question, if I wanted to load initial values for checkboxes, radiogroups, etc. What is a good way to do this?  I have done a lot of the DBAdapter examples for contacts, etc.

Somewhere I read that SQL data for UI should be done as a Background Task in the onCreate() of the activity, but this doesn't work as the UI is displayed before the query is done.

I suppose on my applications initial activity, I could do all my queries and pass the data into the onCreate() of the next activity.  But I think it would provide better performance to do this once the user has initiated the next activity.

Much appreciate any insight.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you provide us the url of that article? Sounds pretty messy to me and I wanna check it.

Comment: If all your'e needing is data for checkboxes and radio buttons, SharedPreferences is the way to go. It is also more lightweight than using a database.

Comment: [link](http://www.android-app-market.com/android-activity-lifecycle.html)

Comment: It may just be my interpretation, I am new to Android.  I will look at SharedPreferences.